# Pass multiple references in a tuple in Rust

Tags: rust, reference, tuples, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a trait with some associated type, and some of its functions take as input a reference of that type:

```rust
trait Trait {
    type Value;

    fn do_something(&self, value: &Self::Value);
}
```

In one structure that implements this trait, `Value` is a tuple, because I need to pass multiple values to `do_something`:

```rust
struct Struct {}

impl Trait for Struct {
    type Value = (i64, String);

    fn do_something(&self, (a, b): &(i64, String)) {
        println!("{} {}", a, b);
    }
}
```

However, when I then use `Struct` in practice, I hit a wall.  Either I do this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = 10;
    let b = "foo".to_owned();
    let s = Struct {};

    s.do_something(&(a, b));  // This works...
    println!("{}", b);  // ...but the borrow checker complains here
}
```

but then I lose ownership of any non-`Copy` type in the tuple.  Alternatively, I can do this:

```rust
fn main() {
    let a = 10;
    let b = "foo".to_owned();
    let s = Struct {};

    let t = (a, b);
    s.do_something(&t);
    let (a, b) = t;
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

which works, but the syntax is extremely heavy.

Does anyone have some idea of how I can accomplish what I want in a more concise way?  I tried to have `Struct::Value` be of type `(&i64, &String)`, but then the borrow checker complains about needing a lifetime for those references, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Another alternative I tried was to use a type parameter (so, `Trait<Value>`) instead of an associated type.  In that case, I can have `Struct` implement `Trait<(&i64, &String)>` without the lifetime issue I had with an associated type.  It works, but in my project it never makes sense for `Struct` to have more than one implementation of `Trait`, so I'd much prefer to use an associated type.

Thanks for your time :-)

Comment: In your first example above can you not use `b.clone()` to get the copy of the string? It's less than ideal but may be useful for your case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to have `Struct::Value` be of type `(&i64, &String)`, but then the borrow checker complains about needing a lifetime for those references, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

It's not possible to avoid lifetimes. All references have lifetimes, some of which the compiler can infer for you and some of which you have to explicitly annotate yourself. Note: the compiler isn't always right so sometimes you have to explicitly annotate lifetimes anyway despite the compiler's inferences.

> In that case, I can have `Struct` implement `Trait<(&i64, &String)>` without the lifetime issue I had with an associated type.

Right, because the lifetimes the compiler inferred for those references happened to work, but you shouldn't be afraid of explicitly annotating them yourself when you need to.

> It works, but in my project it never makes sense for `Struct` to have more than one implementation of `Trait`, so I'd much prefer to use an associated type.

Alright then let's use an associated type. Here's the code with all the necessary lifetime annotations:

```rust
trait Trait<'a> {
    type Value;

    fn do_something(&self, value: Self::Value);
}

struct Struct {}

impl<'a> Trait<'a> for Struct {
    type Value = (&'a i64, &'a String);

    fn do_something(&self, (a, b): Self::Value) {
        println!("{} {}", a, b);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = 10;
    let b = "foo".to_owned();
    let s = Struct {};

    s.do_something((&a, &b)); // compiles
    println!("{}", b); // compiles
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ddeea98b8e38c84c091f635d56fbc364)

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I think I still find lifetime annotations kind-of scary, especially as they tend to creep everywhere, and so I'm always reluctant to use them...  But I hadn't thought of the fact that there's _always_ a lifetime anyway, and it's just that sometimes the compiler adds it automatically for me.

Comment: Yup! I highly recommend reading [Common Rust Lifetime Misconceptions](https://github.com/pretzelhammer/rust-blog/blob/master/posts/common-rust-lifetime-misconceptions.md), I think you'll find it helpful in demystifying lifetimes. Disclaimer: I wrote it.

Comment: This is really extensive :0 Thanks!